# How to circumvent virtual template member functions?

Tags: c++

I have a template class `Field<T>` which inherits from a non-template abstract base class `AbstractField` to be able to store all different kinds of `Field<T> *` types in a `std::vector<AbstractField *>`. My setup is as follows:

```
#include <vector>

class AbstractField
{
    public:
        virtual ~AbstractField() {};
        // Something similar to: template<class T> T getValue() const; ?
};

template<class T>
class Field : public AbstractField
{
    private:
        T d_;

    public:    
        Field(T d) : d_(d) {}
        T getValue() const { return d_; }
};

int main()
{
    AbstractField *f = new Field<double>(0.1);
    // How to call: f->getValue(); ?

    return 0;
}
```

I was wondering what would be the most natural way to call `f->getValue()` since I can't use a virtual template member function in the `AbstractField` class. As far as possible, I would prefer not using boost. Any hints are welcome!

**EDIT:**

Corrected `std::vector<Field<T> >` to `std::vector<AbstractField *>`. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: cast the pointer f to Field<double>*?

Comment: Is it your intention that **every** `AbstractField` should implement some `getValue()`?

Comment: @Matt I already noticed that my question was not clear enough in that I can't simply cast to `Field<double> *` because I actually pass `f` to another function which expects an `AbstractField *`, where I can't determine the underlying type of `f` and hence can't cast.

Comment: @DrewDormann No, it is not my intention that the AbstractField class actually implements `getValue()`. `AbstractField` is intended to be an abstract base class for all kinds of `Field<T>` such that I can create a vector `std::vector<AbstractField *>` with `Field<int>`s, `Field<double>`s, and so on.

Comment: I actually wanted to write `Field<int> *`s, `Field<double> *`s, and so on.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this:

```
template <typename> struct Field;

struct AbstractField
{
    virtual ~AbstractField() {}

    template <typename T> T getValue()
    {
        return dynamic_cast<Field<T>&>(*this)->get();
    }
};

template <typename T> struct Field : AbstractField
{
    T & get();
    // ...
};
```

Comment: @Deduplicator: Sure, why not :-)

Comment: With some modifications, I got your code running. However, I still have to invoke `f->getValue<double>()` to give the compiler the ability to deduce the template arguments because the return type is not part of the function signature. Unfortunately, when passing `f` to another function, I can't determine the template argument to `Field<T>`. As far as I know there is no possibility to get runtime information about the template argument to `Field<T>`. Please correct me if I'm wrong.